# Regex matchin "java.util" but not "java.util.Collections"

Tags: regex

I have a regex:

```
(abc|xyz|java\.util|)
```

However, I would like to ignore `java.util.Collections`. I'm stumped as to how to do this.

Comment: negative lookahead: `java\.util(?!\.Collections)`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as not matching a dot: `[^.]`

Of course, there might be other solutions that work better for you, depending on things like if that's the whole string, if a character is guaranteed to come after it, etc. If you give some more details, I can be more specific.

For example, if it's an import statement, you could just match a semicolon by putting a literal semicolon after it. If you plan to use the bit immediately afterwards, use a negative lookahead: `(?!\.)` If the string will end after the `util`, anchor it to the end with `$`.

If you want to fail on *only* `java.util.Collections` but accept anything else, then you want to use the specific negative lookahead `(?!\.Collections)`. If you want to only allow one thing (say `Random`), you can add`(?:\.Random)?` *immediately* after `java.util` in your current regex.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use the bit afterwards, so the negative lookahead works!

Comment: @poleapple If my answer helped, please upvote and/or accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the end of line character

```
(abc|xyz|java\.util|)$
```

Or [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(abc|xyz|java\.util|)$(?!\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead and use a regex like this:

```
java\.util(?!\.Collections)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yL1jI5/1)**

So, you can add the pattern to your regex and have:

```
(abc|xyz|java\.util(?!\.Collections)|)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]